# How should I extract % delimited tags

Tags: python, text-extraction

I want to get the `%tagname%` from a file and copy them to a dictionary only `tagname` in python.

Comment: What do you have so far, and how doesn't it work?

Comment: What does a _%tagname%_ look like?

Comment: it is A-Z, of any length

Comment: Please, try to ensure that your title is descriptive of your problem and please don't assume part of the answer in your question (in this case, a regular expression is the best way to solve your problem.  In many cases it wouldn't have been).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

this will get you a list of tags

```
re.findall("%([^%]+)%", text)
```

Answer (score 2):

To get the list of tags, you can use the non-greedy version of the + operator, which has the advantage of being simple:

```
re.findall('%(.+?)%', text)
```

In fact, `.+?%` finds all characters of any type (a tag), and stops *as soon as* `%` is found (that's the "non-greedy" part).

In the speed test below, the non-greedy version of this answer is slower than the "not another % sign" version by a factor of almost 2, though:

```
python -m timeit -s'import re; t="%t1% lkj lkj %long tag% lkj lkj"*1000' 're.findall("%([^%]+)%", t)'
1000 loops, best of 3: 874 usec per loop

python -m timeit -s'import re; t="%t1% lkj lkj %long tag% lkj lkj"*1000' 're.findall("%(.+?)%", t)'
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.43 msec per loop
```

Comment: it is however *much* less efficient. It is best practice avoid using non-greedy operators in places where something just as simple will suffice.

Comment: @Jared: You're right, the non-greedy version can be slower.  I find the non-greedy version clearer, though, but this may be a matter of personal taste. :)